# Mimic Navigation in Sketchup / C4D

Tags: modeling, object-mode

**Is there a way of mimicking the navigation controls so they're similar to SketchUp or Cinema 4D?**

SketchUp, which I'm more familiar with, has individual tools for Orbiting, Zooming and Panning. And similarly C4D uses the same O, Z, P, but attached them to pressing a number and the LMB and moving the mouse left or right.

I really want to get to grips with Blender and this would make the process much easier to learn / transition.

Comment: This sounds like a rant rather than a real question. You can customize almost very aspect of Blender input, see https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/preferences/input.html

Comment: You can orbit, zoom and pan in Blender, too. MMB to orbit, `Ctrl` + MMB to zoom, and `Shift` + MMB to pan.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a SketchUp and Blender user as well and I edited the Interface and Input tab to be similar to SketchUp.

Just put everything as shown on the pictures below and you should be good to go.

I should also warn you in advance to expect some issues when zooming in on large objects, so use <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> and buttons <kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>A</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> and <kbd>D</kbd> to move around alternatively (scroll <kbd>Middle Mouse Button</kbd> up or down to speed up or slown down).

Hope it helps!

[image: SketchUp Interface In Blender]

[image: SketchUp Interface In Blender]

Comment: Thank you @ivan Such a big help. I didn't realise about the emulate 3 button mouse + Alt key. Using that feature is much more familiar to me and at the same time allows me to still learn the Blender style of viewport navigation.