# how do i mimic SketchUp navigation settings in blender 2.8?

Tags: 3d-view

I've learned cad from Sketchup and find navigating in it pretty easy and so I want to switch to blender and want to keep navigating like that it'll make it way easier to transition. there's another question similar to this but the whole blender settings panel has changed since then.
It'd be amazing if someone can help me do this in blender 2.8 and later versions please provide screenshots if possible. all help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you please provide more info, for example, please record what you mean about the navigation? In the 3D viewport, If you go to View > Navigation > Walk/Fly Navigation then you can use the WDSA keys to move, if that's not what you mean, please explain in more depth about it.

Comment: Does this answer help? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/81715/mimic-navigation-in-sketchup-c4d

Comment: In SketchUp when you zoom in using your mouse wheel it magnifies/zooms where the cursor is present whereas, in the case of blender the position of the cursor doesn't matter it is always zoomed to the centre of the screen, the situation is similar for orbit / rotate. If possible try SketchUp for a brief movement to understand what I mean. the navigation system provided  in SketchUp is way more flexible and doesn't restrict you the centre of the screen